# How to change *.properties after ant production

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I have 2 .properties files for my project on hybris .
First one is used for CI process and as a result a got 4 zip files with my already built platform(after ant production).
On my prod instance i need to switch to another properties because there are all my connections to extended services such as mysql solr.. etc 
How i can do that without running all ANT steps.

```
. ./setantenv.sh && sync && ant config -Denv=my_new_properties
```

then `./hybrisserver.sh start` doesn't work. 
There is no information on wiki https://cxwiki.sap.com/display/release5/ant+production+improvements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if [Updating Configuration Settings at Runtime](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/1905/en-US/63cb960fd13a47be8f0ce3a9989e161f.html) will be useful for you. You will need to use the `FileBasedConfigLoader` class and the `runtime.config.file.path` property.

Other best practices include using system variables for secure settings like DB URL. See "Using Environment Variables instead of Files for Secure Settings" section in [Configuring the Behavior of SAP Commerce](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/1905/en-US/8b8e13c9866910149d40b151a9196543.html).

Another option you can look at is to have different config folders for different environments (e.g. config-dev, config-prd), and pass it to ant. e..g -Denv=config--dev